# call url without opening in browser on click of button or anchor

Tags: html, angular

I am sending an email to the user which consists of an anchor tag with some URL of my angular application. Basically the scenario is on click of a button from the UI I am calling a rest API.

But now, what I want is it should hit the API without opening any web page on the browser.
Thankx

Comment: Is this for testing purposes of the API endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do anything interactive from an email without opening something in a web browser.

You could probably return a [`204 No Content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) status. I'm not entirely sure how this would behave in different browsers, some might open a tab then immediately close it again, others might show a blank page.

Either way, not giving the user feedback that the link they clicked on had the desired effect is probably a bad idea that will lead to them clicking on it repeatedly and becoming frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

You totally cannot hit a url from an email client without opening browser unless you have intents set in mobile application which in turn will load your url in that application.

And if still you'd like to do so, you need to change your approach. Take user to your application on url click. And make your application do the job for you.